# Removing Add to Cart button for mutiple Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to remove add to cart button for certain products. Found a piece of code that works but it only take one ID. I need to give it multiple ID's so those product's add to cart button can be removed.
Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_hide_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_hide_add_to_cart_button( $is_purchasable = true, $product ) {
return ( $product->get_id() == 118773 ? false : $is_purchasable );}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace comparsion with `in_array` method like this:

```
$nonPurchaseableProductsIds = [118773, 118774, 118775, 118776];

add_filter( 'filter_non_purchaseable_items', function ($product) use (nonPurchaseableProductsIds ) {
    return !in_array($product->get_id(), nonPurchaseableProductsIds);
});
```

This will return `FALSE` if item should be disabled. Of course we assume your $product object has `get_id()` method

Comment: I tried this code and it crashed the site. Then I found that one parenthesis is missing. After that site wasn't crashing but it was making every product unpurchasable rather than those whose ID's has been placed in the array.

Comment: I simply modified your code to search for more than one id. There is no parenthesis missing in the example. I've edited it to remove unnecessary code. probably now it will help you